# in dplyr, how to select and filter on different columns, depending on whether a certain column is in the dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need to extract a few rows & columns from a dataframe:

```r
library(dplyr)

foo <- structure(list(iso3c = c("SWZ", "SVN", "NZL", "JAM", "ESP", "LSO", 
"ATG", "GEO", "GIB", "BHS"), country = c("Eswatini", "Slovenia", 
"New Zealand", "Jamaica", "Spain", "Lesotho", "Antigua & Barbuda", 
"Georgia", "Gibraltar", "Bahamas"), confirmed = c(1, 141, 1522, 0, 148220, 4, 
19, 794, NA, 102), deaths = c(0, 0, 22, 0, 14792, 0, 2, 12, NA, 
11)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
compute_epidemic_curve_data <- function(df, country_code) {
  
  epidemic_curve_data <- df %>%
    filter(iso3c == country_code) %>%
    select(iso3c, 
           country,
           confirmed)
  
  return(epidemic_curve_data)
  
}

print(result <- compute_epidemic_curve_data(foo, "SVN"))
```

However, the data can come from different sources, which means that sometimes the dataframe will have a different structure. Basically, column `iso3c` is called `id`, column `country` is called `admin_region` and an additional column called `tests` is present. E.g.:

```r
bar <- structure(list(id = c("SWZ", "SVN", "NZL", "JAM", "ESP", "LSO", 
"ATG", "GEO", "GIB", "BHS"), admin_region = c("Eswatini", "Slovenia", 
"New Zealand", "Jamaica", "Spain", "Lesotho", "Antigua & Barbuda", 
"Georgia", "Gibraltar", "Bahamas"), confirmed = c(1, 141, 1522, 0, 148220, 4, 
19, 794, NA, 102), deaths = c(0, 0, 22, 0, 14792, 0, 2, 12, NA, 
11), tests = c(2, 282, 3044, 0, 296440, 8, 38, 1588, NA, 204)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now, `compute_epidemic_curve_data` must also return `tests`, i.e., it becomes:

```r
compute_epidemic_curve_data <- function(df, country_code) {
  
  epidemic_curve_data <- df %>%
    filter(id == country_code) %>%
    select(id, 
           admin_region,
           date, 
           confirmed,
           tests)
  
  return(epidemic_curve_data)
  
}
```

The barbaric way to solve this would be:

```r
compute_epidemic_curve_data <- function(df, country_code) {
  
  if("id" %in% colnames(df))
    {
    epidemic_curve_data <- df %>%
      filter(id == country_code) %>%
      select(id, 
             admin_region,
             date, 
             confirmed,
             tests)
  }
  else 
  {
    epidemic_curve_data <- df %>%
      filter(iso3c == country_code) %>%
      select(iso3c, 
             country,
             date, 
             confirmed)    
  }
  
  return(epidemic_curve_data)
  
}
```

but it seems a bad idea to duplicate so much code. Is it possible to have the same function handle two data sources, while at the same time reducing code duplication?

Comment: Should your if statement exclude the option to select 'tests'?

Comment: @Peter good catch - yes, it should. I'll fix the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to choose between possible column names dynamically within a tidyverse selecting function is to use `tidyselect::any_of`:

```
compute_epidemic_curve_data <- function(df, country_code) 
{
  df <- if("iso3c" %in% names(df)) 
           filter(df, iso3c == country_code)
        else 
           filter(df, id == country_code)

  select(df, tidyselect::any_of(c("id", "iso3c","country", "confirmed", 
                                  "admin_region", "date", "tests")))
}
```

Resulting in

```r
print(result <- compute_epidemic_curve_data(foo, "SVN"))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>  iso3c country  confirmed
#>  <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 SVN   Slovenia       141

print(result <- compute_epidemic_curve_data(bar, "SVN"))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   id    confirmed admin_region tests
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 SVN         141 Slovenia       282
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `filter_at` with `matches`

```
compute_epidemic_curve_data <- function(df, country_code) {

   df %>%
         filter_at(vars(matches('iso3c|id')), ~ . == country_code) %>% 
         #or with across
         #filter(across(matches('iso3c|id'), ~ . == country_code)) %>%
         select(matches('iso3c|id'), everything(), -deaths)
   
 }
```

-testing

```
compute_epidemic_curve_data(foo, "SVN")
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  iso3c country  confirmed
#  <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
#1 SVN   Slovenia       141


compute_epidemic_curve_data(bar, "SVN")
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  id    admin_region confirmed tests
#  <chr> <chr>            <dbl> <dbl>
#1 SVN   Slovenia           141   282
```

Answer (score 2):

This avoids some duplication but whether it is more elegant or readable is debatable

```r
library(dplyr)

compute_epidemic_curve_data <- function(df, country_code) {
  
  if("id" %in% colnames(df)) {
    id <- "id"
    sel <- c(id, "admin_region", "tests")
    
  } else { 
    id <- "iso3c"
    sel <- c(id, "country")
    }
  
  epidemic_curve_data <- df %>%
      filter(!!sym(id) == country_code) %>%
      select(all_of(sel), confirmed)
  
  return(epidemic_curve_data)
  
}

compute_epidemic_curve_data(bar, "SVN")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   id    admin_region tests confirmed
#>   <chr> <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 SVN   Slovenia       282       141
compute_epidemic_curve_data(foo, "SVN")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   iso3c country  confirmed
#>   <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 SVN   Slovenia       141
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>